# What my Regexp should be?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, regex

I am trying to get all check constraints from string definition looking like this

```
  CREATE TABLE products(
     id INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
     price         REAL,
     title         TEXT,
     CONSTRAINT price_check CHECK (  price > 0),
     constraint title_check CHECK (length(title) > 5 AND (price <= 100.0))
  );
```

with following regexp `/CONSTRAINT\s+(\w+)\s+CHECK\s+\((.+?)\)/i` but it does't match second constraint, only `constraint title_check CHECK (length(title)` part of it.

How should I change my regexp (if can at all) to get this to work? Specific language dialect of regexp doesn't matter. Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try playing around with one of the online regex tools?

Comment: yes, http://rubular.com/r/EzaW9Jju5Y

Comment: Remove the `?` which makes `+` lazy.

Comment: @SagarPandya: This will fail if a line break enters inside the CHECK parentheses. And if you make the expression multiline, then the regexp swallows too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's Onigmo engine is quite powerful, and allows you to check parentheses nesting.

```
/CONSTRAINT\s+(\w+)\s+CHECK\s+(?<paren>\((?:[^()]|\g<paren>)+\))/i
```

The bit at the end, `(?<paren>\((?:[^()]|\g<paren>)+\))`, is a recursive definition of a balanced parentheses expression: a "paren" is open parenthesis, then either a non-parenthesis character or a "paren", repeating any number of times; then a closed parenthesis; we want one of those now.

Unfortunately, neither Python nor JavaScript allow you to do this.

Comment: Wow, looks little complicated. How can i also capture the name of constraint  (ex. `price_check`) and remove parentheses from captured expression (from this `(price > 0)`)?

Comment: To do that, we'd flip the recursion a bit: `/CONSTRAINT\s+(?<name>\w+)\s+CHECK\s+\((?<content>(?<token>[^()]|\(\g<content>\))+)\)/i`, then check the `name` and `content` captures.

Comment: @therhino: Indeed, for some reason there's extra `\u200c\u200b` in two places (ZERO WIDTH NONJOINER, ZERO WIDTH SPACE) if you copy from my comment, that prevent the regexp from working. No idea how they snuck in there. Here is a correct one (even if it looks exactly the same): http://rubular.com/r/ziY9RWdCJ6

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("CREATE TABLE products(\nid INT PRIMARYNULL,\npriceREAL,\ntitleTEXT,\nCONSTRAINT price_check CHECK (  price > 0),\nconstraint title_check CHECK (length(title) > 5 AND (price <= 100.0))\n  );".match(/^.*constraint.*check.*$/gim));
```